# How do you draw this cross-line reference table/diagram in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, diagrams, draw

How do you draw this in LaTeX:

[image]

My approach would be `enumerate` for the list and `tabular(x)` for the table, but I don't know how to make the crossing arrows across tabel cells (if possible at all)...

Compiling in LuaLaTeX, document class `memoir`.

Comment: IMage you should draw with for example `tikz`, or `tikz-cd` or with `foret` etc, all collected in table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility with use of the `tikz-cd` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c @{\hspace{4em}} l}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=small, baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
                        &   \rlap{aaa}  \\
\llap{x} \ar[ru]\ar[rd] &               \\
                        &   \rlap{bbb}
\end{tikzcd}    &   text    \\   
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=small, baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
                        &   \rlap{aaa}  \\
\llap{y} \ar[ru]\ar[rd] &               \\
                        &   \rlap{bbb}
\end{tikzcd}            &   text    \\
\begin{tikzcd}
\llap{longtext}   &   \rlap{ccc}  
\end{tikzcd}    &   text    
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

An easy and flexible way is using plain TikZ.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\path[left]
(0,0)      node (A) {\r{a}ben}
++(0,-1.6) node (L) {lukket}
++(0,-1.2) node (D) {dobbeltlukket};
\path[right] (A.east)
+(1,.5)  node (A1) {ka} 
+(1,-.5) node (A2) {k\textsuperscript{e}}
+(2.5,0) node{\itshape ingen kort};
\path[right] (L.east)
+(1,.5)  node (L1) {kal} 
+(1,-.5) node (L2) {k\={a}l}
+(2.5,0) node{\itshape ingen reduceret};
\path (D.east)+(1,0) node[right] {kalt}; 

\draw[->] (A.east)--(A1);
\draw[->] (A.east)--(A2);
\draw[->] (L.east)--(L1);
\draw[->] (L.east)--(L2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```